# Is running scan on Hbase faster if running HBase on more than 1 machine?

Tags: hbase

I need to do a scan on HBase table for my adhoc queries. Currently I'm using just a single node. I was wondering if running HBase in distributed mode on more than 1 machine might make it faster. It currently takes around 5 mins to do a scan on 3 million rows on a m1.large EC2 machine.
Any ideas on how to make scan faster are welcome. Currently, I have scan.setCaching enabled which has helped a lot

Comment: You can use mapreduce program to make scans faster and use only mapper class .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, adding nodes will not speed up a scan.  HBase scans are serial for a couple of reasons.

When you make a call like this    `HTable.getScanner(scan)` what is returned is an iterator of   `Result` objects -- upon calling up the   `next()` item, HBase is actually performing another Get-like query for the next row using the parameters of your scan.  All the    `Scan` object does itself is generate a list of row keys and provide an iterator with which you can move through them (it actually does a bit more regarding caching and figuring out which regions the row keys exist on, but we can neglect that).

Beyond the actual mechanisms of a   `Scan` in HBase, there is the matter of [regions](http://hbase.apache.org/book/regions.arch.html) as the underlying architecture for physically storing data on the disk.  The broadest organizing factor in a region file is the column family.  This makes sense, since it allows for less overhead when fetching pieces of data in the same column/family.  Since column families typically exist within one region (or a set of regions, as the size of the column family grows), the effect of parallelizing a scan would be minimal unless you were doing a scan over enough rows to warrant reading from multiple regions, which is generally advised against (after a certain point, it becomes useful to use map/reduce operations to gather information on and compute over your data set).